# Load values via junctions table

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, devexpress, xtragrid

I need to load all the rows from the `ItemToGroup` table into one field separated with a comma, I can't use `String.Join` since I'm using server mode from DevExpress, it loads the data dynamically from the database on demand. And `String.Join` only works on generic lists.

I tried this LINQ Statement:

```
e.QueryableSource = From c In sqlData.ItemStores
Select c.Price, c.Status,
ItemGroupNames = c.ItemToGroups.Select(Function(g) g.ItemGroup.ItemGroupName)
```

Problem is that in the grid column it shows:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`[system.string]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show your field values in UI then you can use [`ColumnView.CustomColumnDisplayText`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic) event and in this event you can use `String.Join`.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(sender As Object, e As CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs) Handles gridView1.CustomColumnDisplayText

    Dim list = TryCast(e.Value, List(Of String))

    If Not list Is Nothing Then
        e.DisplayText = String.Join(", ", list)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It works great for displaying the data, but the auto filter is not working on that column, is there a work around for it?

Comment: @Ezi It is not clear what are you trying to achieve with filter, but if you want to use filter, then you need to have a single value in cell. You can get  this value by using `Aggregate` LINQ method.

Comment: The aggregate code is not compiling.. 2 errors: 
Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.
Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments

Comment: @mempoBu4 I want the user to be able to search for a group by name. (I tried setting the autoFilter mode to display text, but that's not supported in the server mode..)

Comment: @Ezi I have checked my code before posting here. Can you show your data classes and your modified code?

Comment: I added an image from the edmx to the question. when I copy your code I get an error that stringbuilder is not defiend, so I changed it to System.Text.StringBuilder, now I get the errors

Comment: Even if it will compile, I don't think it will work, since EF doesn't allow these methods to be executed on the database.

Comment: @Ezi Yes, you are right. `Aggregate` method is [not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx) by EF.