# Add multiple records to one record

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, devexpress, relationship, xtragrid

I think that should be pretty standard requirement, but I'm struggling ([Load values via junctions table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213326/load-values-via-junctions-table)) on how to display it on a data-grid sufficiently. So I suspect maybe the data design was not done properly, that's why I got stuck here.

I have an item table, every item could have multiple groups, in the data-grid I need to display all the group names assigned to that item in the list.[image: picture of the database structure]

[image: desired results.]

Comment: how are you struggling? what is your current approach? does it not work? why not? if it does, in what way do the results differ from what you were expecting?

Comment: Please see the link to my other open question I have. In short the problem is that I need to aggregate the related values into a single string, without first loading all the data in memory.

Comment: If you want to show data in list for specific column, why don't you use `RepositoryItems`? Or what about **Master-Detail** approach?